# Ошибка в работе сериализатора встроенной модели User в Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Я пытаюсь передать сериализированые данные в ответ на запрос, но данные почему-то не проходят проверку на валидность. Укажите, пожалуйста, ошибку в коде.

serializers.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'id')
```

views.py

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .serializers import UserSerializer

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = User.objects.all()
        serialized = UserSerializer(data=users)
        if serialized.is_valid():
            return Response(serialized.data)
        return Response(serialized.errors)
```

Результат запроса:

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got QuerySet."
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените строчку

```
serialized = UserSerializer(data=users)
```

На следующую

```
serialized = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
```